# Embedded Http server jump seconds on videos where located local

Tags: c#, video, mp4, jwplayer

I need to play video files which are located under client pc.
For this I need to use embedded http server which will be setup on client.
[embedded http server is taken from here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20445/C-Customizable-Embedded-HTTPServer?msg=4370868#xx4370868xx)
If there is more advanced one I would like to learn.
I'm using jwplayer to play mp4 files.
I couldn't make it play and jump on mp4 files.
I have spent lots of time on it,
need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Html5 Video tag to play mp4 videos in any current web browser. And that's easy too. Try this
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: I agree. For this type of application, keep it simple. There's no need for an embedded server or for any player script. You can just use the <video> tag and point directly to the MP4 files on the C: drive. It won't work in IE8, or in FF under WinXP, but every other current browser will play the videos just fine. See http://misterneutron.com/videoTag/

Comment: So are you saying I can play any mp4 file which is located under client pc c drive x folder like c:\x\abc.mp4 ? I can't make it work, not sure what is wrong?

Comment: You have to add the protocol also. So Its more like file:///c:\x\abc.mp4

Comment: Could you provide sample code please? I'm not familiar this type of developments.

Comment: I'm getting "Not allowed to load local resource:" error

Comment: Interesting issue; I could play video on firefox but the problem was chrome, it somehow works multithread and throws error!

Comment: See my answer, below (can't post code in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

This works in all current browsers - IE11, FF 36, Chrome 41:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>Video Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width='640' height='360' controls poster='file:///C:/Users/JT/Videos/Samples/wildlife.jpg'>
<source src='file:///C:/Users/JT/Videos/Samples/wildlife.mp4'>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It gives me the same error which you can see from ; http://postimg.org/image/kapjv3k7l/

Comment: Don't run it from localhost. In short, there is just no need for any sort of PC-based server. Just run it from the C: drive.

Comment: I don't get exactly what you mean. The video is already loaded from e drive. I need to play video in the web page.

Comment: You are making this WAAAY more complicated than it really is. See: http://misterneutron.com/ss000343.png and http://misterneutron.com/ss000344.png

Comment: I can't make it that way, Members will add video files whenever they want. And then I need to make those videos playable from our web project which is located at our web server.

Comment: Round and round we go. If you're running this from an actual web server, then you can't access video files on the PC - that would violate all web security rules in existence. The video files have to be on the web server as well. Back to my demo page, where the index.html is on the server, the MP4 is on the server, and the JPG is on the server: http://misterneutron.com/videoTag. I'm beginning to think you should find another line of work.

Comment: Actually I could make the video file to play from embedded web server from firefox and ie, but chrome gives me error. Simply I'm sending response.SendFile(@"E:\test_videos\test.mp4", "video/mp4"); and localhos:8080/video.mp4 play on browsers other than chrome! I'm stuck!

Comment: @kubilay Why don't you re-articulate your requirement and problem situations nicely. May be then we can help you better.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't understand what he's trying to accomplish. If this is a web site on a web server, the videos need to be on the web server. If the videos are on a PC, there's no need for a server of any description. If it's a web site that allows users to provide videos, those videos need to be uploaded, then played from the server.

Comment: I know it sounds weird but this is what I'm supposed to do; Here is the structure; There will be a web server which our project will be located , there will be embedded http server which will be located on client storage and there will be clients. We want users to upload videos from their local to client storage via our web project which is the thing. Then we need to play videos from client local storage with jump on videos capabilities. We could make the video upload but there need to be access from web server to embedded http server, but we couldn't make it jump on videos from embeddedserver

Comment: This is a stunningly misguided structure. You seem to be going out of your way to create an overly-complicated, clumsy setup. Best of luck!